# Can't change image source from outside class

Tags: python, kivy

I want to change the source path of an image from outside of the class/screen where the image is shown.

I have a callback function called `my_callback`, which will be called at some point during runtime of the app:

```
def my_callback():
    # do stuff
    MDApp.get_running_app().manager.get_screen('my_class').ids.imageID.source = "my_image.png" 
    MDApp.get_running_app().manager.current = "my_class"
```

I would expect the above two lines of code to do the following:

1. Switch the kivy screen to the `my_class` screen
2. Update the source of the image with the id "imageID" (as defined in my .kv file).

Outcome (1) is successful, but outcome (2) is not: rather than showing the image "my_image.png", a black shape is shown of equivalent dimensions to the image "my_image.png".

How can I fix this?

Note that `MDApp` is used here in place of `App`, as I am using the KivyMD library for my project.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know why the method I posted in the question doesn't work, but I have found an alternative solution.

The function `my_callback` now looks like this:

```
def my_callback():
    # do stuff
    MDApp.get_running_app().manager.current = "my_class"
    image = AsyncImage(source='my_image.png') 
    MDApp.get_running_app().manager.get_screen('my_class').ids.floatLayoutID.add_widget(image)
```

And in the .kv file, there is a nested `floatLayout`:

```
<MyClass>:

    name: "my_class"

    FloatLayout:
        FloatLayout:
            id: floatLayoutID
```